# C A negative sign to a variable without assigning it

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I am looking at some C code, and the following example is confusing me.

```
theta = PI*0.5;
if(xn< 0.0 ) -theta;   // ???
```

When I compile, the compiler says the expression result is unused, and that's what I think is happening: `theta` with the negative sign is not assigned to anything.

There are a couple parts in the source code like this, and I'm wondering if I'm missing anything since I'm not very well-versed in C.

On the other hand, the code is provided by the government, and there is a part that checks if `someVariable < 0.0` when `someVariable` is a constant that is a positive float. So I'm also thinking it's just the lazy programmer being lazy. Is this what's going on?

Comment: Since when "provided by the government" is a seal of quality? :) The oode indeed has no effect and would be optimized out by any good compiler.

Comment: @DYZ Actually I meant "provided by the government" as highly suspicious

Comment: The statement `-theta;` does nothing; the compiler will optimize away the whole line.  Maybe it should read `theta = -theta;` — that probably makes sense and does change the variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- that seems likely, or perhaps the intention was `--theta;`?

Comment: Since `theta` is Pi/2, `theta = -theta` sounds like a more plausible typo than `--theta`, but we can only guess.

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually, as long as it does nothing I'm happy. It's the source code of a gov't web app in service. Even though it's a typo, my app will behave the same as the gov't service, so it's all good.

Comment: @DavidBowling: I think `π/2 - 1` is less plausible than `-π/2` on the whole — but it isn't clear without more context, which is why I left 'probably makes sense'.  Certainly, it could be `--`; I'm making a semi-educated guess that it isn't what was intended.  I wonder if the unit tests should be spotting this?  (…No laughing in the back there — unit tests are allowed in government produced code too!…)

Comment: BTW, the said code is in both C version and the JavaScript ported version. They seriously don't effing care.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- I agree with you; but given so little information, and since it is very easy to understand the decrement operator as a typo here (one missed keypress), I just thought that I would mention it. (And yes, you did catch me laughing about the unit tests!)

Comment: now we know why so much government code is junk.  Reminds me of the fortran program in an early space mission where a 0 and a o misuse was not caught, that caused the loss of a land rover vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with you, it is meaningless.

May be interesting to see the next use of 'theta", to check if it was a bug.
Eg: if 'theta' was used only as 'cos(theta)' then this lazy writing is useless and act like a comment because 'cos()' is an even function. Different case would be if an odd function is used.

I mean, cos(x)=cos(-x) indeed sin(x)!=sin(-x) .. This code is correct in the first case but it is wrong on the second case.